# Code runnig with "IndexError: list index out of range" at the end

Tags: python, list, indexing

I run a code that gives me the result I want but it shows at the end of this result an "IndexError: list index out of range".

Here is a part of the data I have:

```
AMI;ZFAMIEM1;NBAMI702;DSDOU904;WHD93;SAGEM_WHD93_stbmib_02.29.82;08:3E:5D:5F:7A:42;2018-01-26 12:14:35;1516965275678;/app//wakeup;\N
AMI;ZFAMIEM1;NBAMI702;DSDOU904;WHD93;SAGEM_WHD93_stbmib_02.29.82;08:3E:5D:5F:7A:42;2018-01-26 12:14:35;1516965275824;/app//connect;ethernet
AMI;ZFAMIEM1;NBAMI702;DSDOU904;WHD93;SAGEM_WHD93_stbmib_02.29.82;08:3E:5D:5F:7A:42;2018-01-26 12:14:35;1516965275970;/app//tv_off;\N
```

Here is my code:

```
ligne = data.split("\n")

for i in ligne:

    col = i.split(";")
    print(col[1])
```

The result I am looking for and that I get with my code is:

```
ZFAMIEM1
ZFAMIEM1
ZFAMIEM1
```

---

```
IndexError                                
Traceback (most recent call last)
  <ipython-input-53-4d9c2e4b9014> in <module>()

  5 for i in ligne:
  6     col = i.split(";")
--> 7     print(col[1])

 IndexError: list index out of range
```

If you have any idea on how I can avoid  this error, please  help me. Thank you!

Comment: Make sure your col has values in it. `if len(col) > 0: print(col[1])`

Comment: (not so) wild guess: you have an empty line at the end of the file? when you do `i-split(';')` on it, since there is no `;`, you don't get a list with at least two elements, so `col[1]` fails.

Comment: i suggest you have a look at the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#module-csv). and are you sure about the `\N`? end-of-lines should be `\n`.

Comment: @MCBama That should probably be `if len(col) > 1`.

Comment: This may just be the way you typed this out on here, but your data contains "\N" upper case and you split at "\n" lower case.  This is keeping it from splitting.

Comment: @khelwood True 'nuff. I was assuming he didn't simply have a blank line at the end. A blank line would give a length of 1 while EOF should be length of 0

Comment: @MCBama  , I make sure that my col has values in it. By running                 if len(col) > 0: print(col[1]) and if len(col) > 1: print(col[1]) I get the result with the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help. I am using `filter` to remove any empty lists after the split.

**EX:**

```
s = r"""AMI;ZFAMIEM1;NBAMI702;DSDOU904;WHD93;SAGEM_WHD93_stbmib_02.29.82;08:3E:5D:5F:7A:42;2018-01-26 12:14:35;1516965275678;/app//wakeup;\n AMI;ZFAMIEM1;NBAMI702;DSDOU904;WHD93;SAGEM_WHD93_stbmib_02.29.82;08:3E:5D:5F:7A:42;2018-01-26 12:14:35;1516965275824;/app//connect;ethernet\n AMI;ZFAMIEM1;NBAMI702;DSDOU904;WHD93;SAGEM_WHD93_stbmib_02.29.82;08:3E:5D:5F:7A:42;2018-01-26 12:14:35;1516965275970;/app//tv_off;\n"""
for i in filter(None, s.split(r"\n")):
    col = i.split(";")
    print(col[1])
```

**Output:**

```
ZFAMIEM1
ZFAMIEM1
ZFAMIEM1
```